# regarding autocorrelation and derivation of original signal

Tags: autocorrelation

$$r_x(t)=\begin{cases}
2-2t    ,&   0 \le t \le 1\\
2+2t ,& -1 \le t \le 0
\end{cases}$$

So how do I get original $x(t)$ from this?

I tried integrating the equations, and the value I got was $1$.

Comment: Your question is un-understandable, but if what you are asking is what signal $x(t)$ has autocorrelation function $$R_x(t)=\begin{cases}2-2t,&0\leq t \leq 1,\\2+2t,&-1\leq t \leq 0,\\0,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ then integration is not what you need to do (and the value 1 that you got for the integral is wrong too).  By the way, $x(t)$ is not unique.

Comment: **Hint:** Your autocorrelation looks like a triangle. Autocorrelation is convolution with a flipped version of the same signal. Which function when convolved with itself looks like a triangle?